# MySQL will no longer run after installation of Postfix/Dovecot/etc. with Palegray's Automate

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I recently downloaded and installed this software on my VPS:

http://www.palegray.net/projects/automate/pdm/debian-6

It's a package for easy installation of postfix, dovecot, and MySQL mail server. The installation appeared to go just fine, but I believe something went wrong. I can no longer access anything on my website that uses MySQL (so the forums, wiki, etc.) and it won't even run through the command line.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

...is the error I get whenever I try to run MySQL, but the "mysql --help" command seems to work just fine.

Any of you guys know what's up?

Comment: Are you sure you have started the mysql server?

Comment: Yes, I did start the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this had to do with a user/pass mixup in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf. Looks like what I installed changed those values, but for those that ever have the same problem be sure that the values in debian.cnf are the same user/pass values you want to use for your stuff. Encrypting it wouldn't hurt but debian.cnf is unsafe in general. Thanks for the help, everyone.

So, if you ever install this software but already have MySQL etc., then make sure you check debian.cnf.